# Ionic: Cannot retrieve local JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, ionic-framework

In my Ionic application I'm trying to retrieve local JSON data and load it into my application. I have set up a http.get in my javascript to retrieve my data but for some reason it isn't loading into the application. I'm unsure why. I think i have made a mistake in my html to load in the data but i'm unsure what it is.

JS:

```
.controller("WorkCtrl", function($scope, $http, $ionicModal) {

   $http.get('../file.json').success(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
})
```

HTML:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-controller="WorkCtrl" ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "Item":"People",
   "Item":"Work",
   "Item":"Meetings",
   "Item":"Date",
   "Item":"Time",
}
```

Comment: shouln't `$scope.data = items;` be `$scope.items = data;`?

Comment: I've changed it but still isn't loading :/

Comment: What's the issue? Please update the question to reflect the correction that Jeff pointed out.

Comment: Does the JavaScript Console show any errors? Does the Net tab of the Developer Tools show a successful request/response?

Comment: Does `console.log`ing `items` give you the value you expect? Where does `items` come from?

Comment: You did not make the correction that Jeff suggested. Your question code is wrong.

Comment: GET http://localhost:8100/file.json 404 (Not Found)  - I'm trying to find why it can't find it.

Comment: That changes the nature of your question considerably. It's no longer about Angular or Ionic, but the path to your file.

Comment: I've fixed that. Now i'm getting ReferenceError: item is not defined

Comment: You haven't fixed it *in your question*: `$scope.data = items;` This is misleading to those trying to help you.

Comment: Opps, changed it now. Now i'm not getting any errors but it isn't loading the data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

HTML:

```
  <ion-list ng-controller="WorkCtrl">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.id }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller("WorkCtrl", function($scope, $http, $ionicModal) { 
  $scope.items = [
    { id:  9 },
    { id: 10 },
    { id: 11 },
    { id: 12 },
    { id: 13 },
    { id: 14 },
    { id: 15 },
    { id: 16 }
  ];

})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try to sort their http, I recommend use

(file.json is in = www folder)

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'file.json'})
.success(function(data){
   console.log(data.Items);
   $scope.items = data.Items;
 })
 .error(function(){

 })
 .finally(function(){

 });
```

Second, the JSON format, it might be better this way:

```
{
  "Items":[
    { "Item" : "Under 5/6/7/8/9s"},
    { "Item" : "Under 10s"},
    { "Item" : "Under 10s"}
   ]
 }
```

In case you want to add more values to their arrangement.

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.Item}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```